# Unity3D: default parameters in C# script

Tags: c#, unity, mono

Accordingly to this [thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8649/optional-function-parameters-in-javascript-and-c.html), it seems that default parameters aren't supported by `C#` script in `Unity3D` environment.

Declaring an optional parameter in a C# scirpt makes `Mono` Ide complaint about it:

```
void Foo(int first, int second = 10) // this line is marked as wrong inside Mono IDE
```

Anyway if I ignore the error message of `Mono` and run the script in Unity, it works without notify any error inside Unity Console.

Could anyone clarify a little bit this issue?
Particularly:

- Are default parameters allowed inside C# scripts?
- If yes, are they supported by all platforms?
- Why Mono complains about them if the actually works?

Comment: In fact you can build in Visual Studio targeting .NET 3.5 with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As of Unity 3.1, default arguments are supported in C#. As Mono Develop doesn't support them, so if you're using the debugger you need to select Tools > Preferences > Unity > Debugger and turn off "Build project in MonoDevelop".
2. Yes supported.
3. As before C# 4.0, doesn't allow for default parameters. For this reason it was not at Unity3D. Mono complains why, Mono can answer the best. But I think they will add at next version.

Comment: I just find out that MonoBehaviors with default parameters aren't allowed if the class is declared inside a namespace. Don't know if it is a bug.